# Swapping the route's model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have an app with a cart displayed on top of the page, in the application template. Then, in the application route I define the model, along the lines of:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Em.Route.extend
  model: (-> 
    @store.find('cart', @session.get('cart_id')
  ).observes('session.cart_id')
```

When a user logs in, I want to replace that cart with the one loaded from the server. What is the best way to approach this?

I got to the point, where the cart is loaded to the Ember Data store, the observer block gets executed, but the template is not updated with the new model. Or, maybe, I should use something entirely different for this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure but you can try observe this in `beforeModel` hook. The reason is `model` hook already set the `content` property in `ApplicationController`, that's why your template can't find the right model. `beforeModel` can let you observe the correct `cart_id` before `model` hook return the promise. I think you should use `beforeModel` to fetch the `cart_id` then use it in `model` hook to fetch the right model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the model hook is called by the router while hooking up models for the current route.  If you'd like to change the model on a controller, just grab the controller and set the `model` property to the new model.

Assuming the session exists in the application route

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Em.Route.extend
  updateModel: (-> 
    @store.find('cart', @session.get('cart_id')).then (record) => 
      @controller.set('model', record)
  ).observes('session.cart_id')
```

(I mixed and matched coffeescript, I only know it from stackoverflow questions, so sorry if it's wrong)

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wedup/1/edit

Comment: Amazing! I edited the coffeescript syntax a bit, if you don't mind (the fat arrow (``=>``) translates to ``_this = this; function(...){_this.controller.set(...)}``).